# Constrain return type of generic function

Tags: rust

I have this function:

```
fn io_convert_int<F, T>(from: F) -> io::Result<T>
where
    T: TryFrom<F>,
    <T as TryFrom<F>>::Error: std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static,
{
    from.try_into().map_err(|e| io::Error::new(InvalidInput, e))
}
```

I want to call it specifying only the return type and let `T` be inferred. I know I can do

```
io_convert_int::<_, SomeT>(some_f)
```

but this can be a problem when I don't want to have to rely on the arrangement of the type parameters for the function (which are often very complex or subject to change). What I want is to do something like

```
io_convert_int(some_f)?::<SomeT>
```

How do I do this? The only other way I can think of is to have a variable with the expected return type like

```
let to: SomeT = io_convert_int(some_f)?;
```

This has the disadvantage of having to break up expressions, which I am not always okay doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There once was [type ascripiton](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0803-type-ascription.html), but it's since been [de-rfc'd](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3307-de-rfc-type-ascription.html).

Currently I think your extra variable is the best way, though you could use [`std::convert::identity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/fn.identity.html) to assert the type inline instead:

```rust
identity::<SomeT>(io_convert_int(some_f)?)
```

Comment: Love the `identity` hack!